# gmock base class constructor instantation with another instance

Tags: c++, unit-testing, constructor, googlemock

In the below sample, I would like to mock "class TestB", since "class TestA" has an external dependency.

**Sample code:**

```
*file : testA.h*
template <typename s>
class TestA : public class TestBase
{
.....
struct ConstructionToken
{
//`Code for construction token`
};
explicit TestA(ConstructionToken&& token) noexcept
        : TestBase(token.ID, token.Con)
.....
};

*file : testB.h*
class TestB : public class TestA
{
.....
TestB(ConstructionToken&& token)
: TestA<TestB>(std::move(token)){}
.....
};

*file : testC.h*
class TestC : public class TestB
{
.....
TestC(ConstructionToken&& token)
: TestB(std::move(token)){}
.....
};
```

**Test code:**

```
*File : Dependency_test.cpp*
TEST_F(DependencyCheckTest, DependencyCase1)
{
.......
// auto token = preconstruct the instance.
TestC cObj(std::move(token));
}
```

**Question**
In the test code object created for the "TestC" class.

1. Is there any way to gmock the "class TestB" constructor?
   "class TestA" has an external dependency, so I don`t need to call TestA.

---

**Note:**
Apart from the constructor, I am able to mock other methods.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way that I know about to omit the call to the ctor of the base class - ctors are never virtual in C++ and hence you cannot override them.

In your case I would suggest to make all the classes inverit from a pure-virtual class with default ctor and default virtual dtor and all the other methods pure-virtual if possible. It ensures better abtracion and removes problems like this.